# Knowing when pointed to object changes

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

In C++ is there a way, using raw pointers or otherwise to trigger some action when the pointed to object changes?

Scenario:

```
class A
{
    double var;
    B var2 {&var};
}

class B
{
   double* pVar;
   B (double* _var ) { pVar = _var};
}
```

I have functions inside class B that will get called whenever member variable *var* changes value. At the moment I would need these functions to be public so they can be called manually from class A, this could be achieved by using a setter for *var*. If I wanted to keep the function inside class B private (as it is called by other events internal to class B) what are my options?

Comment: In short: No, there isn't.

Comment: You can't do this with raw pointers. You should read about the Observer design pattern.

Comment: The title of this question and first sentence are about one thing but the rest of the question is about calling private member functions from another class. Anyway, there’s no way to magically have a function be called when a variable changes. If you want to do something like that use a setter function , possibly let A accept a callback that gets called from var’s setter. Deal with the private/public issue via `friend`.

Comment: Your question is essentially the same as asking to "trigger an action when an `int` changes". Pointers are values like most others.

Comment: Such a facility is not built into the core C++ language.  Boost [Signals2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/signals2.html) provides that kind of functionality, which I think is patterned after Qt's signals-and-slots.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the observer pattern.
So what you need is to trigger a function call to another object
when the value of your object is changed through a setter method.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// the class with the member variable that can change
// and to which another class can react.
// This is a simple example where only one "callback" function
// can be registered. In the typical observer pattern
// there can be multiple callbacks registered.

class Observee
{
public:

    // set notification function to a function that does nothing
    // "null strategy pattern"
    Observee() :
        m_notify_observer_fn{ [](int) {} }
    {
    }

    // let another object pass in a function that will be called
    // when the value is changed
    void OnValueChanged(std::function<void(int)> notify_observer_fn)
    {
        m_notify_observer_fn = notify_observer_fn;
    }

    // to change the member value AND notify the other object
    // that the value has changed we need a setter function.
    void set_value(int value)
    {
        // check if the value really has changed
        if (m_value != value)
        {
            // set the member value
            m_value = value;

            // then notify the observer of the new value
            // by calling the notification function
            m_notify_observer_fn(m_value);
        }
    }

private:
    std::function<void(int)> m_notify_observer_fn;
    int m_value{};
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The class that wants to get a notification when the value
// of the other class changes (role is an Observer)

class Observer
{
public:
    explicit Observer(Observee& observee)
    {
        // Set the callback in the observee to the OnValueChanged
        // function of this object (the function passed is called a lambda funtion)
        observee.OnValueChanged([this](int value)
        {
            OnValueChanged(value);
        });
    }

private:
    void OnValueChanged(int value)
    {
        std::cout << "Value changed to " << value << "\n";
    }
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    // make instances of both classes.
    Observee observee;
    Observer observer{ observee };

    // now set the value
    // this will change the member in observee
    // and then call the method in the observer for you
    observee.set_value(42);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I also like your approach

Answer (score 1):

> Question : If I wanted to keep the function inside class B private (as it is called by other events internal to class B) what are my options?

You can call a private function of class B while coding class A using friend attribute.

```
class B 
{
    friend class A;
private:
    void foo() { std::cout << "using foo." << std::endl; }
};

class A
{
private:
    B b;
public:
    void bar(){ b.foo(); }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

About the callback to be call when a double variable change its value:
No you can't do it with a raw pointer.

You got at least two ways of doing it.
The first way is what you outlined : use a setter function.
The second is to make a class that own the value and that overloading operator= is able to call the callback.
I'll sketch something here to make you understand better:

```
template<class T>
class Owner{
    using FuncType = std::function<void(Owner<T>&)>;
    
public:
    Owner(){}
    Owner(const T& init){
        _var = init;
    }
    Owner(const Owner<T>& init){
        _var = init;
    }
    operator T(){
        return _var;
    }
    auto& operator =(const T& rvalue){
        _var = rvalue;
        _on_change();
        return *this;
    }
    auto& operator =(const Owner<T>& rvalue){
        _var = rvalue;
        _on_change();
        return *this;
    }
    const T& get() const { //don't make it non const or
                           //you will lose ownership to value of _var
        return _var;
    }
    void set(const T& val){
        _var = val;
        _on_change();
    }
    void set(const Owner<T>& val){
        _var = val;
        _on_change();
    }
    
    void set_handler(FuncType func)
    {
        _func = func;
    }
    
    
private:
    void _on_change(){
        if(_func)
            _func(*this);
    }
    
private:
    T _var{};
    FuncType _func{};
};



int main()
{
    Owner<double> var{};
    var.set_handler([](Owner<double>& ch){
        std::cout << "Value changed: " << (double) ch << std::endl;    
    });
    
    var = 1.0;
    return 0;
}
```